# How can I add fields in SharePoint list in single line of text column using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I have 5 columns in a SharePoint list.
In order to reduce the number of columns to one, I should have all other 4 fields to be added to one column using JSON.

when i try

```
{
"status" : "approved"
"maildate" : "09-09-2018"

}
```

It does not give me anything. the column will have no value in it.

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: What SharePoint version is this?

Comment: online site it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding it programmatically, you will probably need to escape/encode the value. Also, the example you wrote is missing comma after "approved".

Otherwise, adding it to SharePoint single line text field works fine if done using browser.

Comment: No i am not doing using program. Just putting JSON in single line of text with comma after approved.But it does not work.can you please provide me an example. i have a sharepoint list having 5 column.Instaed of five i want to use one and put other 4 fields in json format as single line of text column.But it gives me blank column or sometime it just dn display the list at all. – user78210 2 mins ago